# Return std::array from a function as a range

Tags: c++, c++20, stdarray

Say I have two arrays:

```
constexpr std::array<int, 3> a1{1, 2, 3};

constexpr std::array<int, 5> a2{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

What is the right way to convert them to ranges of the same type to make it possible to call `process_result` function with their return values?

```
constexpr void process_result(RangeType range) { for (auto elem: range) { //do something with elem }
```

So the question is what is `RangeType`.

An obvious solution is to replace `std::array` with `std::vector`, but I wonder to know what to do with `std::array`.

Comment: Can we see how `process_result(RangeType range);` is declared/defined?  You might not need to do anything as an array is already a range.

Comment: @NathanOliver It has a parameter of `RangeType` and it is non-template.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `RangeType` is what I am asking about.

Comment: [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span)`<const int>`?

Comment: *"An obvious solution is to replace `std::array` with `std::vector`"*. I don't see how it "defines" `RangeType`...

Comment: @Jarod42 `RangeType` is `std::vector` in this case

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, it is it.

Comment: I'm also confused about the question - would a struct with begin and end pointers, used in the same manner as `std::begin` and `std::end` be a good `RangeType` ? I see it tagged as `c++20` so I guess it has something to do with ranges, but I haven't heard of any such "RangeType"

Comment: `using RangeType = std::array<int, 3>;` would work the same way with `std::array` as your obvious solution with `std::vector`... So our confusion about your question.

Comment: @Jarod42 it was a type, the arrays are of different sizes, updated the post

Comment: Then would a template<RangeType> that calls `std::begin` and `std::end` on RangeType work, or are you looking for a non-template solution ?

Comment: @JulienBERNARD `std::span` is better than this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use (non owning) [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) to allow any contiguous ranges:

```
constexpr void process_result(std::span<const int> range)
{
    for (auto elem: range) {
        //do something with elem
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't necessarily need a *function*, and can instead use a function template, then you can make it more generic by supporting all ranges; not just contiguous ones:

```
constexpr void
process_result(const auto& range)
{
    for (const auto& elem: range) {
        //do something with elem
    }
}
```